# Tkinter Alignment within Frames

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the GUI monitor I'm working on: 
[image]

My code is atrocious as I feel like I'm hacking it together, but I'm hoping the issue of my alignment has to do with the way I'm setting up the frames, so possibly I could just spare you the minor details and post that. If not, let me know and I can post more.

This is what I have for the roots:

```
weather_root = Frame(root, bg = 'orange').grid(row = 0, column = 0,sticky = NW)

forecast_root = Frame(weather_root, bg = 'blue')
forecast_root.grid(row = 0, column =1, rowspan = 8,  sticky = NSEW)

time_root = Frame(forecast_root, bg = 'red')
time_root.grid(row = 0, column = 7,sticky = NE)

commute_root = Frame(time_root)
commute_root.grid(column = 0)

quote_root = Frame(forecast_root, bg = 'yellow')
quote_root.grid(column = 0, columnspan = 8, rowspan = 4,sticky = 'S')

#I have these spanning columns to get in the description of the article
news_root = Frame(root, bg = 'green')
news_root.grid(row = 8, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = W)

sport_root = Frame(root, bg = 'purple')
sport_root.grid(column = 0, columnspan = 4,sticky = W)

scores_root = Frame(root, bg = 'indianred')
scores_root.grid(row = 8, column = 7, sticky = N)

football_root = Frame(scores_root, bg = 'orange')
football_root.grid(column = 0)

business_root = Frame(football_root, bg = 'yellow')
business_root.grid(column = 0)

# This color doesn't seem to be getting picked up
stocks_root = Frame(business_root, bg = 'black')
stocks_root.grid(column = 0)
```

What I would like to do is push the scores/business news/stock quotes to the left up against the world news and have the time at the top be inside the blue box so that box spans across the whole top.

I tried putting it in the same frame as World News, but got this: 
[image]

This is additional (not critical), but really blew it up when I tried so didn't press my luck, but I would like to have the stock quotes be in separate columns within that section so I could put in some conditional formatting. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use additional frames for the top and bottom and then the frames you have go inside them in the position you want.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x500+1000+10")
blue_frame=tk.Frame(root, bg="blue", height=100, width=200)
blue_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, stick="nsew") ## <-- sticky=fill both columns

green_frame=tk.Frame(root, bg="green", height=300, width=200)
green_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)

yellow_frame=tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow", height=300, width=100)
yellow_frame.grid(row=2, column=1)

tk.Button(root, text="Exit", bg="orange",
          command=root.quit).grid(row=20)
root.mainloop()
```